# Linux Fedora 19 - iptables failed to start

Tags: linux, fedora, iptables

i'm kind of new to Linux and i'm trying to start the firewall of iptables, and it failed.
I don't know why, can you help me please? image attached with the status of iptables

http://s23.postimg.org/kyohzsdsb/526be85302df1d8c.png

Comment: I think http://unix.stackexchange.com or http://serverfault.com might be better places to ask this.

Comment: show us the last lines of `journalctl -u iptables.service`.

Comment: Hi Nazar554, here is the output :
http://jsfiddle.net/YQv5H/1/

Comment: I am having the very same problem (and iptables used to work for me till a while ago); is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

In Fedora 19 iptables are replaced by firewalld. It is supposed to be backward compatible, but maybe it is not.

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FirewallD